# How to get frame of detected Barcode using Google Vision api for Barcode detection

Tags: java, android, frame, barcode-scanner, google-vision

The google Vision's Barcode detection API works fine and gets the result of the scanned barcode using Android. But I didn't find any way to get the frame from which the barcode is detected. Is there any way to get that exact frame?

Comment: Did you come up with something? I was thinking about getting static frame, creating bitmap and analysing it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [detect(Frame)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector#detect(com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame)) instead of [receiveFrame(Frame)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector).

When using **receiveFrame()**, you can only receive the barcode results returned by a processor:

```java
class BarcodeTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Barcode> {
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;

    BarcodeTrackerFactory(GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
        mGraphicOverlay = graphicOverlay;
    }

    @Override
    public Tracker<Barcode> create(Barcode barcode) {
        BarcodeGraphic graphic = new BarcodeGraphic(mGraphicOverlay);
        return new GraphicTracker<>(mGraphicOverlay, graphic);
    }
}
```

Whereas **detect()** is a synchronized method. So you can save the results with the exact frame.